# "de plus" and "des plus" in Gide and Madame de La Fayette

Tags: sens, expressions, adjectifs

I am trying to understand *de plus* and *des plus* as found in these passages.

From chapter 7 of *La porte étroite* by André Gide:

> Quand Alissa m’accordait quelques instants, c’était en effet pour une conversation **des plus gauches**, à laquelle elle se prêtait comme on fait au jeu d’un enfant.

From part 1 of *[La Princesse de Clèves](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Princesse_de_Cl%C3%A8ves,_%C3%A9dition_Lepetit,_1820/Premi%C3%A8re_partie)* by Madame de La Fayette (édition Lepetit, 1820):

> Jamais cour n’a eu tant de belles personnes et d’hommes admirablement bien faits ; et il semblait que la nature eût pris plaisir à placer ce qu’elle donne **de plus beau** dans les plus grandes princesses et dans les plus grands princes.

**QUESTION**

1. I understand that the Gide phrase *une conversation des plus gauches* means *a most awkward conversation*. How does it come to mean that?
2. What is the literal meaning of *ce qu’elle donne de plus beau* in Madame de La Fayette?
3. How would you say in French:

   > It seemed nature had taken pleasure in placing in the grandest princesses and princes what it gave (or had to give) of the **most** beautiful.
4. How would you say in French:

   > It seemed nature had taken pleasure in placing in the grandest princesses and princes what it gave (or had to give) of the **more** beautiful.
5. Is there any syntactic or other interaction I should be aware of between the two usages (Gide and La Fayette's)?

**BACKGROUND**

**About question 1**

If I were left to myself I would have guessed that *des* was *de* + *les* and that there was something implicit after *gauches*, maybe *choses*. So the thing would have seemed to mean *a conversation of the most awkward things*

But one of my grammar books says that *un monsieur des plus charmants* is equivalent to *un monsieur très charmant* and in English *a most charming gentleman*.  Here too, left to myself, I would have come up with something like *a gentleman of the most charming qualities*, by supplying *qualities* myself.

Should I simply accept that *un* or *une* + singular form of noun + *des plus* + plural form of adjective equals *a most* + adjective + singular noun? Or is there some deep explanation?

**About questions 2, 3 and 4**

Please never mind how *donne* should be rendered in English.  That's not my question here.

My guess as to question 2 is that the phrase is about the superlative. It would make little rhetorical sense to talk of the *more* beautiful as if what was the *most* beautiful were then reserved for kitchen maids and stable hands. So I am wondering why not put a *le* in there somehow.  Maybe expressions such as *au plus* and *du moins* are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I guess you could see it as *parmi les plus gauches (des conversations)* becoming abbreviated to *des plus gauches*. Maybe. I cannot guarantee that this is how it came to be, but it could be a reasonable explanation. See note below.
2. I think it means *what natures gives (us) that's most beautiful*, i.e. the most beautiful that nature has to give us.
3. *what it gave (or had to give) of the most beautiful* seems to beg a *of ...*. It feels to me like something is missing in this sentence. This would work better for me: *It seemed nature had taken pleasure in placing in the grandest princesses and princes the most beautiful it had to give*. In that case I would translate to:

   > On aurait dit que la nature avait pris plaisir à mettre ce qu'elle avait de plus beau dans les plus grandes princesses et les plus grands princes.
4. If we again nudge the English sentence to: *It seemed nature had taken pleasure in placing in the grandest princesses and princes the more beautiful it had to give*, then my translation would be:

   > On aurait dit que la nature avait pris plaisir à mettre ce qu'elle avait de plus beau dans les plus grandes princesses et les plus grands princes.

   With *beau*, it turns out the same! With *meilleur* instead of *beau*, you could have *de mieux* in 3, and *de meilleur* in 4. But even so, I am not sure the reader would pay a lot of attention to a possible difference between 3 and 4 in French. It feels to me like another case of *couper les cheveux en quatre*. I think we hear/read this as a semi-ready-made, semi-predictable formula and don't dwell on possible ambiguities or nuances. I don't think the reader would pause and ask himself/herself: "the author wrote *de meilleur* and not *de mieux*! Is the author implying that it had not placed *the very best* in them, but only something one step below, just *good*?" I even think that in this expression *de mieux* and *de meilleur* have in fact the exact same meaning. I don't know if a nuance really exists.
5. Nothing that comes to mind right away. I'm sure there will be other contributions with more to say here :-)

   ***Note 1***: About the background for 1 - I think the correct way to understand *un monsieur des plus charmants* would be *un monsieur (parmi) les plus charmants (des autre messieurs)* i.e. the plural refers to other *messieurs*, to whom this one is compared and said to be the most charming. In my opinion, this plural is not required because there are many *charmantes (qualités)*, but because there are many *messieurs*. Same for the other expression: *des plus gauches* is plural because there are many *conversations*, as noted above.

   ***Note 2***: About *de + les = des* in the first expression. I think that *les* is recovered if we understand the sentence as ***parmi** **les** plus gauches **des** conversations*. But not: ***parmi** les conversations des choses les plus embarrassantes* (*gauche* maybe doesn't work here_). It is the *conversations* that are *gauches* themselves, no implicit "awkward thing" is needed to make sense of the expression. I believe the second expression *que la nature eût pris plaisir à placer ce qu’elle donne de plus beau* should be analyzed in the same way: *de plus beau* can be understood as *de plus beau (parmi toutes les choses qu'elle a faites)* (which is to say, everything that exists ;-)

Comment: On the English in 3 and 4, all I meant was *what nature had to give from her store of the most beautiful things (or qualities)*. Please forgive the English if it sounds bad. I was trying mimic what I thought was going on in French.

Comment: Yes, I think I got the meaning. I allowed myself to suggest a slight variant in English, and then I went ahead and translated that to French. I think I didn't betray the meaning you intended too much.

Comment: So, the Madame de La Fayette sentence is ambiguous between the superlative and the comparative (i.e. could mean either)--just like your sentence in 3 and 4? / Is *à la Platon* a reference to the Athenian philosopher? / See my reference to *au plus* and *du moins*.

Comment: Yes, the philosopher who talked about Ideas/Forms, such as the Idea of the Beautiful, of the Just... I am not sure you should pay too much attention to the nuance of superlative and comparative... IMHO, the reader hears/reads a semi-ready-made expression and doesn't necessarily dissect it or feel put off by the ambiguity :-)

Comment: @Catomic - I added an important clarification at the end - I think there is some confusion about the plural in the expression.

Comment: Even in *de mieux* I note that you don't want any *le*. I guess I should simply accept *donner (avoir) de mieux (plus...)* as a form, and separately accept *au plus* and *du moins* (with *le* in them), and be on the look out for other forms, which may or may not want *le* in them.

Comment: Yes I can't place a _le_ anywhere - let me comment on that too.

Comment: @Catomic I think we nailed it this time :-) Is the explanation about how this expression helpful? You need to change your point of view a little.

Comment: Oh yes, the *parmi* bit is completely intuitive. It totally demystifies. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "de" in the first "des" is, as Frank said, more or less equal in meaning to "parmi". That is, "une conversation des plus gauches" means "one of the most awkward conversations" by way of "a conversation (selected from among) the most awkward".

The second "de" is not the same, as you seem to be aware. Its sense is quite near the bottom of the CNRTL page [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) (search: "Après les pron. neutres indéf."). Its function is simply to introduce a qualifier that might not sit right elsewhere in the sentence:

> Elle nous donne quelque chose de beau. (Remarquez: *beau* est masculin, même après *chose*.)
>
> She gives us something beautiful.

In my grammar, it is not possible for the superlative to be expressed via this exact construction.

You could instead say "ce qu'elle donne du plus beau", though grammatically it would be a little different (and, as you seem to intuit, more in line with your first phrase). This would be literally "what she imparts from among the most beautiful things (that there are to impart)".

Incidentally, there are plenty of results for "quelque chose du plus" in a regular Google search and in an Ngram search, though it's hard to find an exact match:

> [quelque chose du plus grand charme](https://books.google.ca/books?id=h21aSoJseeoC&pg=PT94&lpg=PT94&dq=%22quelque%20chose%20du%20plus%22&source=bl&ots=jkQd1vy-uS&sig=XYxTzN5QD1Eju-mfZZwXq6m7Fwk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz5Oyf547SAhXs1IMKHVNgCFQQ6AEINzAE#v=onepage&q=%22quelque%20chose%20du%20plus%22&f=false) (something of the greatest charm -- not an adjective)
>
> [quelque chose du plus fort que ce que...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Z6l8qWsk8TYC&pg=PA343&lpg=PA343&dq=%22quelque%20chose%20du%20plus%22&source=bl&ots=BeIceuF0Ds&sig=2mewMkBEv2YdWSeq18fwEYkFqUU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz5Oyf547SAhXs1IMKHVNgCFQQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22quelque%20chose%20du%20plus%22&f=false) (one of the things that is stronger than...; more like your first sentence. Also archaic source)
>
> [quelque chose du plus simple au plus complexe](https://books.google.ca/books?id=tz3X50fXjBUC&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=%22quelque%20chose%20du%20plus%22&source=bl&ots=CsxmhwSkag&sig=imaJbaTtHp8J-wWvCfzlGebfOOY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz5Oyf547SAhXs1IMKHVNgCFQQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=%22quelque%20chose%20du%20plus%22&f=false) (*de ... à* as *from ... to*)
>
> [quelque chose du [plus loin dont on ait connaissance]](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hB5WAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173&dq=%22quelque%20chose%20du%20plus%22&source=bl&ots=rUSsju7QD-&sig=8hAPygBg5WmqHQXEJKXY7Skvxjw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz5Oyf547SAhXs1IMKHVNgCFQQ6AEIQDAG#v=onepage&q=%22quelque%20chose%20du%20plus%22&f=false) (something from among the farthest things we know about)

That last one is pretty close.

But to return to the phrase you cited: when I say that the superlative can't be expressed via that construction, I mean strictly in terms of the grammar. In terms of the *sense* of the phrase, I think English would indeed best render it as a superlative.

> ce qu'elle donne de plus beau
>
> the most beautiful things she imparts

For your fourth question, the English isn't clear -- and this is a great example of why the comparative in English wouldn't be a good match of what is technically a comparative in French. If you had something to compare it to:

> ce qu'elle donne de plus beau que ...

Compare this to the "du plus fort que ce que" to get a pretty exact view of the difference between the two constructions:

> quelque chose de plus fort que ce que ...
>
> Something stronger than that which ...
>
> quelque chose du plus fort que ce que ...
>
> Something from among those things that are stronger than ... (Grammatically supposes the existence of such a class of things)

Comment: This _de_ is not the same as in the first sentence? I would have said it was about the same construction: _des plus gauches_, _de plus beau_. Note: it is not _de beau_, but _de plus beau_.

Comment: So this one: _quelque chose du plus grand charme_ is ambiguous without more context! :-) But for a different reason. It could mean _something of the most charming_, if that is correct, i.e. there is "the most charming", and we are talking about "something of that most charming". There is also _quelque chose du charme de ..._, which is again different, and would be "something of the charm of", i.e. a bit of that charm, something undefinable, but which reminds us of that charm of ... .

Comment: If "grammatically" the original La Fayette sentence cannot express the superlative, do we have the option of changing *de* in it to *du* so as to force it to become a "grammatical" expression of the superlative? Or is that somehow bad (not allowed by grammar, not natural sounding, etc.)?

Comment: @Frank The first *de*, as you said, could be paraphrased *parmi*, but the second one couldn't. It would have to be paraphrased *qui est*. Or another rendering might be *qui est parmi le* -- which certainly highlights how dang close they are in meaning, but how unequivalent they are as syntactic items.

Comment: @Catomic You could change *de* to  *du*, and then the *de* that is "in" *du* would be the first *de* (*parmi*) rather than the second *de* (*qui est*). So it'd sound perfectly fine, but would be a subtly different syntax.

Comment: @LukeSawczak - the second one is amenable to the same explanation, IMHO: _ce que la nature a de plus beau (parmi toutes les choses qu'elle a faites)_.

Comment: @Catomic The very subtle change in meaning from *de* to *du* would also be from "what she imparts that is the most beautiful (of the things she imparts)" with *de plus beau* to "what she imparts from among the most beautiful things (that exist)" with *du plus beau*.

Comment: @Frank Quite right. The only different would be where the building blocks of the sentence lie: "ce qu'elle donne de plus beau [parmi toutes les choses qu'elle a faites]" vs. "ce qu'elle done du [plus beau (parmi tout ce qui existe)]". I think you might have beat me to this punch just now, though...

Comment: @LukeSawczak. I just barely got my head to accept that distinction--or mechanically. I need to ponder and let it sink in and really become meaningful to me. (This is great.)

Comment: @LukeSawczak - if you say _ce qu'elle donne du [plus beau (parmi tout ce qui existe)]_, the meaning is again slightly different. It means nature gives you a bit of what is the most beautiful ... There is now an idea of giving you some of what's most beautiful, but not all. That was not IMHO present in either of the 2 exemples initially given by Catomic.

Comment: Yes, once using the *parmi* sense, there will be a sense of selection.